# How to delete an email address from all contact lists programmatically?

Tags: list-manager, contact

I am trying to delete a user's email address from all Lists in List Manager, which the user might be subscribed to in Sitecore 8.1. Is there a particular API available to do this?

Comment: You can just add user to Global Opt-out Contact List. I suggest you a series of articles about EXM subscribe/unsubscribe functionality https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/12/17/managing-the-unsubscribe-part-1/

Comment: @x3mxray Does this apply to Sitecore 8.1?